# What is the point of using a cryptographic sequence number if you're not using it as a nonce?

Tags: authentication, md5

OSPF features the use of `Auth Crypto Sequence Number` however, from reading the RFC it would appear the sequence number is *not* being used as a nonce.

> In addition, a non-decreasing sequence number is included in
> each OSPF protocol packet to protect against replay attacks.
> This provides long term protection; however, it is still
> possible to replay an OSPF packet until the sequence number
> changes. - [OSPF MD5 Authentication Draft II](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ospf-md5-02)

Correct me if I am wrong but isn't the whole point of a cryptographic sequence number to protect against replay attacks? If so, why would you not use a nonce? Is there any benefit to this? Or is this just a weakness which was never improved upon?

I'm also struggling to make the distinction of "in the long term less of an issue" - how does that even make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence number is *not* designed for cryptographic purposes, merely to mitigate pathological routing bugs. According to [RFC 6863 § 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6863#section-3), the sequence number does not prevent replay attacks within the session, nor does it prevent replay attacks against subsequent sessions:

> As discussed, neither version of OSPF meets the requirements of
> inter-connection or intra-connection replay protection.  In order to
> mount a replay, an attacker needs some mechanism to inject a packet.
> Physical security can limit a particular deployment's vulnerability
> to replay attacks.  This section discusses the impacts of OSPF
> replays.

The sequence number itself is arbitrary, as long as it is non-decreasing. To be specific, a message is dropped if the sequence number for that message is less than that of the previous message. As such, the number can be anything from an incrementing counter value to a high-precision timestamp of when the packet was created. Note that a host going down resets the number to zero, so an attacker can force the sequence to repeat merely by DoSing one of the routers.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the draft, I think that the purpose of using a sequence number in place of a nonce is because handling nonce in practical situations is very difficult. We need to keep a directory of the used nonces and then do a search through them. You can maintain a heap for the already seen nonces, but the problem is of storing them.

In the draft it says - "The value used in the sequence number is arbitrary, but two suggestions are the time of the message's creation or a simple message counter". This gives a very clear idea that the way they want sequence numbers to be used in practice is to use them in a strictly increasing fashion so that there is no need to store all the seen values and just the latest one can be stored. 
I also think that using increasing sequence numbers which wrap (start to repeat) around after a decent amount of time would also work because by the time the sequence numbers repeat, the validity of the message will long be expired.

Comment: Right, so this doesn't prevent replay attacks at all and simply relies on the fact that of the sequence number changing?

Comment: You cannot replay the messages until the sequence number reaches its period. After that, you can.

Comment: But surely that is still bad? If I can replay after it reaches it's period I can still obtain information I shouldn't be able to, correct?

Comment: The draft says this - "The mechanism does not afford confidentiality, since messages stay in the clear", which means that messages can be read, that is not something which their security model concerns.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that line, my apologies. Okay, so technically they are still vulnerable to replays it just shouldn't be a problem as you can only so it after the message is expired essentially?

Comment: They are just concerned with the case that someone cannot replay the same message in a very short time since the original one was sent. This can be handled easily by taking a period large enough that messages expire by the time the period ends.

Comment: If you can read a message doesn't mean that replays are allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79227/discussion-between-joshua-jones-and-mayank).